TS2367: types `State.RUNNING` and `State.INTERRUPTED` have no overlap
I'm currently developing a multithreading library and have encountered an issue related to TypeScript enum comparisons within the Thread.execute() method. The problem arises specifically when comparing the state property.
Here is snippet of the erroring code:
37. if(this.#state === State.INTERRUPTED) {
38.     this.#reset()
39.     break
40. }

The error:
TS2367: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types State.RUNNING and State.INTERRUPTED have no overlap.
Here is the whole code:
 1. import { ThrottleCallback, TransferData } from '../../types/core/Threads';
 2. import ThreadInterface, { Mode, State } from '../../types/core/Thread';
 3. import { HybridExecutor } from '../../types/core/Executor';
 4. import { Task } from '../../types/partials/TaskPool';
 5. 
 6. export default class Thread implements ThreadInterface {
 7.     #executor: HybridExecutor;
 8. 
 9.     #state: State = State.IDLE;
10. 
11.     #progress: number = 0;
12. 
13.     constructor(Executor: new() => HybridExecutor) {
14.         this.#executor = new Executor();
15.     }
16. 
17.     async execute(data: TransferData, mode: Mode = Mode.SEQUENTIAL): Promise<any[]> {
18.         if (this.#state === State.RUNNING) await this.#waitForThreadIdle();
19. 
20.         this.#state = State.RUNNING;
21. 
22.         const responses: any[] = data?.responses ?? [];
23. 
24.         const tasks: Task[] = data.pool.pool;
25. 
26.         while (data.pool.length && this.#state === State.RUNNING) {
27.             // Get the next task & remove it from the pool
28.             const task: Task = tasks.splice(0, 1).at(0)!;
29. 
30.             // Sequential mode: set the message to the response of the previous task (if exists)
31.             if (mode === Mode.SEQUENTIAL) task.message = task?.message ?? responses.at(-1);
32. 
33.             // If throttle is set, wait for its completion. If it fails, terminate the thread
34.             if (data.throttle) await this.#waitForThrottleSuccess(data.throttle).catch();
35. 
36.             // Check if the thread has been interrupted
37.             if (this.#state === State.INTERRUPTED) {
38.                 this.#reset();
39.                 break;
40.             }
41. 
42.             // Run the task and get the response
43.             const response = await this.#executor.run(task.method, task.message);
44. 
45.             // Check if the response is an error and gracefully terminate the thread
46.             if (response?.error) {
47.                 console.error(response.error);
48.                 break;
49.             }
50. 
51.             // Save the response
52.             responses[task.index!] = response;
53. 
54.             // Execute the step callback
55.             const progress: number = responses.filter((response) => response !== undefined).length / data.poolSize;
56.             this.#progress = progress;
57.             data.step?.(responses[task.index!], progress * 100);
58.         }
59. 
60.         this.#reset();
61. 
62.         return responses;
63.     }
64. 
65.     terminate(): void {
66.         this.#state = State.IDLE;
67.     }
68. 
69.     #reset(): void {
70.         this.#state = State.IDLE;
71.         this.#progress = 0;
72.         this.#executor.terminate();
73.     }
74. 
75.     #waitForThreadIdle = async (): Promise<void> => {
76.         return await new Promise<void>(async (resolve): Promise<void> => {
77.             const interval = async () => {
78.                 if (this.#state === State.IDLE) return resolve();
79.                 else requestAnimationFrame(interval);
80.             };
81. 
82.             interval().then();
83.         });
84.     };
85. 
86.     #waitForThrottleSuccess = async (throttle: ThrottleCallback): Promise<void> => {
87.         return await new Promise<void>(async (resolve) => {
88.             const interval = async () => {
89. 
90.                 const throttleResult: boolean = await Promise.resolve(throttle()).catch((e: Error) => {
91.                     this.#state = State.INTERRUPTED;
92.                     throw `Throttle error: ${e}`;
93.                 });
94. 
95.                 if (throttleResult) return resolve();
96.                 else requestAnimationFrame(interval);
97.             };
98. 
99.             interval().then();
100.         });
101.     };
102. 
103.     get state(): State {
104.         return this.#state;
105.     }
106. 
107.     get progress(): number {
108.         return this.#progress;
109.     }
110. }

Here is the enum representing the different states:
export enum State {
    IDLE = 'idle',
    RUNNING = 'running',
    INTERRUPTED = 'interrupted'
}

The only thing I noticed is that the error is somehow linked to the line 20 this.#state = State.RUNNING. For example, if I change this assignment to this.#state = State.INTERRUPTED, the error shifts to another comparison:
26. while (data.pool.length && this.#state === State.RUNNING) {
...

Thanks in advance <3
Fix the TS2367: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types State.RUNNING and State.INTERRUPTED have no overlap. error on line 37.

It seems like TypeScript doesn't expect this.#state to change during await this.#waitForThrottleSuccess(…)

Btw, never pass an async function as the executor to new Promise! This looks very much like the Promise constructor antipattern. And interval().then(); makes no sense either

Thanks for the tips, @Bergi! The part with interval.then(); is just there so the IDE doesn't complain about missing then() or await.

Well no, the IDE (linter?) was absolutely right to complain. Try to understand why it complained, not find a weird way to suppress the warning.

@Bergi that's what I thought, but I also can't understand this TypeScript behavior.

@Bergi well it's kind of a way I came up to not wait for an async function

You actually do want to wait though… throw out the entire implementation of the method and replace it by async #waitForThreadIdle(): Promise<void> { while (this.#state !== State.IDLE) await new Promise(requestAnimationFrame); }

"Thanks for the tip, @Bergi! I've already rewritten it as follows:
return await new Promise<void>( (resolve): void => { const interval =  () => { if (this.#state === State.IDLE) return resolve() else requestAnimationFrame(interval) } interval() }).
Using a while loop could potentially overload the main thread, especially when waiting for multiple threads to become idle.

No, it doesn't. Please understand how async/await works. (Also, none of the code you've shown involves "threads").

@Bergi

It does in my case. while loop has no limitations and will attempt to run as fast as possible, which is not desirable for me.
By threads I meant Thread instances.

For more details, you can check out the project on GitHub if you are interested. (core/Thread, core/Threads)

No, it doesn't. The while runs only so fast as the await in its body, same as yours but more efficient and better at error handling - which, admittedly, doesn't matter here, it's only more concise. Thanks for the link, I see you are actually using workers in your thread executors. However, to determine their idleness you should not go polling with requestAnimationFrame at all, you should only listen to the messages from the workers.

@Bergi omg, you are right xD ! Thanks for checking my code, always helpful to have another pair of eyes review it.
